# Javascript AddEventListener works only once

Tags: javascript, function, dom, addeventlistener

In the code below I'm trying to generate 8 random numbers between 1-80, put them into divs with clicking run button, empty numbers array and erase inside of divs with reset button.

Run button works only once. It can't create new elements for numbers array  and write again.

What is wrong with the code ?

```js
var numbers = []
var luckyNumber;
var x = 1;

function playRandom() {
  while (x <= 8) {
    luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80 + 1);
    if (numbers.indexOf(luckyNumber) == -1) {
      document.getElementById('k' + x).innerHTML = luckyNumber;
      numbers.push(luckyNumber);
      x++;
    }
  }
}

function resetRandom() {
  for (var z = 1; z <= 8; z++) {
    document.getElementById('k' + z).innerHTML = ' ';
  }
  numbers = [];
}

var runX = document.getElementById("run");
runX.addEventListener("click", playRandom);

var resetX = document.getElementById("reset");
resetX.addEventListener("click", resetRandom);
```

```html
<div id="k1">K1</div>
<div id="k2">K2</div>
<div id="k3">K3</div>
<div id="k4">K4</div>
<div id="k5">K5</div>
<div id="k6">K6</div>
<div id="k7">K7</div>
<div id="k8">K8</div>

<button id="run">Run</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: initialize your x inside playRandom function

Comment: can you provide your html ?

Comment: 3th question related to this code... I knew I had already seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `var x = 1` at the beginning of the `playRandom()` function, otherwise the `(x <= 8)` condition won't let the function run anymore further.

```js
var numbers = []
var luckyNumber;
var x = 1;

function playRandom() {
  var x = 1;
  while (x <= 8) {
    luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80 + 1);
    if (numbers.indexOf(luckyNumber) == -1) {
      document.getElementById('k' + x).innerHTML = luckyNumber;
      numbers.push(luckyNumber);
      x++;
    }
  }
}

function resetRandom() {
  for (var z = 1; z <= 8; z++) {
    document.getElementById('k' + z).innerHTML = ' ';
  }
  numbers = [];
}

var runX = document.getElementById("run");
runX.addEventListener("click", playRandom);

var resetX = document.getElementById("reset");
resetX.addEventListener("click", resetRandom);
```

```html
<div id="k1">K1</div>
<div id="k2">K2</div>
<div id="k3">K3</div>
<div id="k4">K4</div>
<div id="k5">K5</div>
<div id="k6">K6</div>
<div id="k7">K7</div>
<div id="k8">K8</div>

<button id="run">Run</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: yaah totally agree @kind user

Comment: Is there even any reason for `x` to be a global variable?

Comment: @Barmar Agreed.

Comment: @Barmar No,But I wonder why playRandom() doesn't look to the top of the code for x =1 ?

Comment: @user7580495 It does, but only **once** when the script is loaded. If you click the button you just call the function, not the whole script.